# I need to run Action Method in Partial View but it redirect me to another action

Tags: c#, razor, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I need to run Partial View from action method as a child action method but it redirect me to another view.

1- I tried to use `Html.Action("myAction","myController")` and I use `[ChildActionOnly]` data annotation but without any benefit

2- I tried to use `Html.RenderAction("myAction", "My Controller")` and I change the action method as `PartialViewResult` and `return PartialView("View", myData)` but without any benefit.

3- I tried to use JQuery AJAX but without any benefit also.

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHqYt.jpg)

[What I Expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk8gC.jpg)

** This is the controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _GetUserRoles(string UserName)
{
    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@UserName", UserName);
    try
    {
        IList<GetUserRolesViewModel> roles = Identitydb.Database.SqlQuery<GetUserRolesViewModel>("admin.sp_GetUserRoles @UserName",
        ((ICloneable)param1).Clone()).ToArray().ToList();
        return View(roles);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = ex.ToString();
        return RedirectToAction("ErrorSaveData");
    }
}
```

** This is PartialView Code

```
@model IEnumerable<AMSIdentity.Controllers.GetUserRolesViewModel>


@if (Model == null)
{
    <table></table>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed container" style="margin-top: 5%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br />

    @Html.ActionLink("Return Back", "RemoveRoleFromUser", "Manage")
}
```

** This is Parent Page Code

```
    ViewBag.Title = "RemoveRoleFromUser";
    var error = ViewBag.Error as IEnumerable<String>;
}

<h2> Remove role from user </h2>
<ul></ul>
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Username", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.Editor("UserName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    @Html.Label("Role Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.Editor("RoleId", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Remove" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="row container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Get user roles </h3>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("_GetUserRoles", "Manage", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <hr />
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Username", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.Editor("UserName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Get rules" class="btn btn-default btn-success" id="btnRules"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               @Html.Partial("_GetUserRoles")
            </div>
        </div>


    </div><!--Second Column-->

</div> <!--End of row-->


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

** This is the view Model

```
public class GetUserRolesViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Username")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Role Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

** This is AJAX Code that i used to run partial view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).ready(function ()
    //{
        $("#btnRules").click(function (e)
        {
            var UserName = $("#UserName").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Manage/_GetUserRoles',
                dataType: 'html',
                data:{"UserName": UserName},
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $('#listRules').html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                     alert('Failed to retrieve rules.');
                }
            });
        });
    //});

</script>
```

** Route Picture
[Route Config Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCn5z.jpg)

I expect to run the Action Method (_GetUserRoles) Partially in the same view of RemoveRoleFromUser.

Comment: Please share the jQuery ajax code as well. Using jQuery ajax should have worked.

Comment: @akg179 I add the JQuery AJAX code above.

Answer (score 1):

your return must be a PartialView() and not a view. view() will return a complete view where as PartialView() will return a partial view. So yo need to change your

```
return View();
```

to

```
return PartialView("YourPartialViewName");
```

and if you need to pass a parameter to your partial view

```
return PartialView("YourPartialViewName",roles);
```

if you are rendering a partial view from your View them you can use Html hepler

```
return PartialView("~/views/ABC/PartialViewName.cshtml", Yourmodel);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193763/discussion-on-answer-by-shubham-singh-i-need-to-run-action-method-in-partial-vie).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing

```cs
return View(roles);
```

to

```cs
return PartialView(roles);
```

or

```cs
return PartialView("_GetUserRoles", roles);
```

Using ajax

```cs
$.ajax({
    url: '/Manage/_GetUserRoles',
    dataType: 'html',
    data:{"UserName": UserName},
    success: function (data)
    {
        $('#listRules').html(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
         alert('Failed to retrieve rules.');
    }
});
...
<div class="row container">
   <div id="listRules" class="col-md-12">
      @Html.Partial("_GetUserRoles", Model.Roles)
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Andre Sanson, Thank you for your answer, I try what you tell me but it didn't work, If you can apply the AJAX way to my code and write it, this will be more better for me to understand what you tell me, thank you again.

Comment: @ali I edited my answear to show how to do it with ajax + partial view.

Comment: Hi @andre Sanson, I used your new edited answer and it is not work, I solve the problem by ViewData['']

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your ajax call hits the controller action. And the partial view needs to be placed in the parent view code at-

```
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.Partial("_GetUserRoles")
    </div>
</div>
```

Based on these assumptions, you need to change few things in your code:

1. return `PartialView` instead of `View` from the action. Something like this:

```
return PartialView("_GetUserRoles", roles);

// the partial view name mentioned here is just a sample based on the context. 
//You need to give your partial view's name here.
```

2. add an `id` attribute to the div inside which you have written `@Html.Partial("_GetUserRoles")`. Something like this:

```
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="userRoles">
    </div>
</div>
```

3. within the `success` function in the ajax method, you need to use the `id` attribute set in above step and populate the `data` inside it. Something like this:

```
success: function (data)  
{  
    $('#userRoles').html(data);
}
```

4. Install the `Microsoft.Jquery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` and `Microsoft.Jquery.Unobtrusive.Validation` in your project. Then add the reference of these two within your view file. Something like this:

```
@section scripts{  
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery{version}.js") 
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")   
}
```

This way you should be able to see the partial view within your existing view itself.

Comment: Hi @akg179, Thank you for your answer, I did what you tell me but i got the same problem.

Comment: is your ajax method getting invoked and are you getting the response in correct format?

Comment: Yes my AJAX Function is invoked and it give me the data then redirect to the new view, I don't know why?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: JQuery varsion 3.3.1

Comment: I think the unobtrusive-ajax js needs to be installed in your project and referred into the view. I have updated the answer with this step (#4) please try.

Comment: did u install the two js nuget packages and then add the references into the view file?

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the answer

I use ViewData[""] rather than PartialView and i put one parameter in the same action result to check which view i will use.

** Action Method RemoveRoleFromUserConfirmed

```
public ActionResult RemoveRoleFromUserConfirmed(string UserName, string RoleId, string btnval)
        {

            if (btnval == "Remove")
            {
                if (UserName == null && RoleId == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@RoleId", RoleId);
                SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@UserName", UserName);
                try
                {
                    Identitydb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("admin.sp_RemoveUserFromRole @RoleId, @UserName", param1, param2);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = ex.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("ErrorSaveData");
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Roles");
            }

            else if (btnval == "Get Rules")
            {


                SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@UserName", UserName);
                try
                {
                    IList<GetUserRolesViewModel> roles = Identitydb.Database.SqlQuery<GetUserRolesViewModel>("admin.sp_GetUserRoles @UserName",
                    ((ICloneable)param1).Clone()).ToArray().ToList();

                    string result = "";

                    foreach (var item in roles)
                    {
                        result += "<tr>"
                                 + "<td>" + item.Name + "</td>"
                                 + "<td>" + item.Id + "</td>"
                                + "</tr>";
                    }

                    ViewData["getrules"] = result;
                    return View();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = ex.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("ErrorSaveData");
                }

            }
            return View();
        }
```

** This is the view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RemoveRoleFromUser";
    var error = ViewBag.Error as IEnumerable<String>;
}

<h2> Remove role from user </h2>
<ul></ul>
<div class="row container">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveRoleFromUser", "Manage", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Username", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.Editor("UserName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    @Html.Label("Role Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.Editor("RoleId", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Remove" name="btnval" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">


        <div class="row container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Get user roles </h3>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveRoleFromUser", "Manage", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <hr />
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Username", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.Editor("UserName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Get Rules" name="btnval" class="btn btn-default btn-success" id="btnRules" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row container">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="listRules">
               <!--Data Come from ViewData-->
                <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed container" style="margin-top: 5%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Role Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Role Id
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @Html.Raw(ViewData["getrules"])
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div><!--Second Column-->

</div> <!--End of row-->



<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Roles")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

> I put the name of button same in two buttons (remove and get rules)
>   after that i checked the value of the button in ActionMethod and if it
>   is remove it will do some function and if it is get rules i will use
>   ViewData[""] to put the view.

**Regards,

Ali Mosaad

Software Developer**